healthcheck on localhost or service name in docker compose/swarm mode
Help me understand why healthcheck does not work by service name when I use multiymls configuration.
I have main.yml and prod.yml
I have commonmainprod.yml which simply contains all in one.
Service name webui:
services:
  webui:
    container_name: webuiprice${APP_ENV_PROD:-prod}
    image: ${REGISTRY_ADDR}/price/webui:${APP_ENV_PROD:-prod}_sw_${VERSION:-0.1.0}
    ....

Healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://webui:8090 || exit 1
      interval: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 20s
      timeout: 10s

no_proxy:
no_proxy == 'localhost,webui,price-prod_webui

When i deploy stack from :
docker stack deploy -c main.yml -c prod.yml  stack-prod 

healthcheck get error:
curl --fail http://webui:8090 -v
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,webui,price-prod_webui'
* Could not resolve host: webui
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: webui

When i deploy stack from :
docker stack deploy -c commonmainprod.yml  stack-prod 

Healthcheck get OK:
curl --fail http://webui:8090 -v
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,webui,price-prod_webui'
*   Trying 10.0.2.216:8090...
* Connected to webui (10.0.2.216) port 8090 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: webui:8090
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*

Why error?
UPD
Другое поведение
In prod stack healthcheck:  test: curl --fail http://webui:8090 after start in cluster first get check errors
*0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: webui\n"*
When then i start other test stack with healthcheck: test: curl --fail http://localhost:8090 this stack up okey, and prod stack suddenly starts to conduct checks on curl --fail http://webui:8090 - OK
Prod stack has networks overlay mode
  network1:
    name: traefik-reverse-proxy
    external: true
  network2:
    name: price-net-prod
    external: true

test stack has networks overlay mode
  network1:
    name: traefik-reverse-proxy
    external: true
  network2:
    name: price-net-test
    external: true

WHY?

Two problems with this approach:

The service name represents a virtual IP for the service, which load balances to service replicas. If there is more than one replica, the health test won't reliably check the health of "this" instance.

Docker does not register the IPs for tasks that are not yet healthy in its service mesh. That is, until there is at least one healthy replica the service dns will not resolve.


The tl;dr is you always want to perform health checks against localhost.
